# Wordpress - count post that contain certain text

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get a count of how many post contain the text "emailed-image", to use down the line but something here is tripping me up and I think its just my syntax, but I can't quite seem to catch what it is.

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->post WHERE $wpdb->post.post_content LIKE %emailed-image% ");
```

I try echoing out the count but it's not displaying anything, almost like the query isn't returning any results, but there is 3 entries in the db with the text I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried that query in something that runs direct SQL queries? Does it work? I would think you'd need single quotes around the `LIKE` value

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things. It's `$wpdb->posts` not `$wpdb->post` and you need single quotes around the search term like this:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%emailed-image%' ");
```